# Create attr_reader methods while setting the values for the according instance variables in the initialize method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I am looking for way to create the according attr_reader methods while setting the values for the according instance variables in the initialize method? For example, the following code:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_reader :hello
  def initialize( arg)
    @hello = arg
  end
end
```

I am looking for way to write as follows:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize( arg)
    some_method_as_described_in_question( @hello, arg) 
  end
end
```

Does a method doing what I have described exist in the Ruby built-in Classes and Modules?

Comment: nope, there is no such method.

Comment: This seems like something very convient to have, is it an issue with access control? Why is it not included?

Comment: It would probably be weird to include a method that you call in an instance method (`initialize`) that changes things on the class, i.e. on other instances as well. Or do you only want it to set a reader on the current instance? You could do that with `define_singleton_method` in Ruby 1.9: https://gist.github.com/be3485dde76c0da72a00 Perhaps you could clarify the question?

Comment: @KurtRudolph, because it's not clear exactly what that would do. If it's supposed to add a fully-fledged attribute reader in the class, then it doesn't make sense to put it in the initialize method. Then every time you create a new object, it would be doing the same attribute assignment on the class level. If you want to do it on the *eigenclass* for reason of dynamically setting attribute readers per instance, see my answer. If it's just for "convenience" then it doesn't even make sense, since it would doing something useless or different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the eigenclass from within the method and set the attribute there:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(arg)
    (class << self; self; end).send(:attr_reader, :hello)
    @hello = arg
  end
end
```

That way each instance's eigenclass will have that attribute reader. But really it only makes sense to do things that way if the attribute name is dynamic, and can vary from instance to instance. If it's always `hello`, I don't see any drawback to just defining it in the class like your original code block.

For example, if you are dynamically passing in the attribute name, you could do it like this:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(attr, arg)
    (class << self; self; end).send(:attr_reader, attr.to_sym)
    instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", arg)
  end
end
```

This is compatible with Ruby 1.8. Taking a tip from @HenrikN in the comment to your question, you can use `define_singleton_method` in Ruby 1.9:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(attr, arg)
    define_singleton_method(attr) { instance_variable_get("@#{attr}") }
    instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", arg)
  end
end
```

Comment: Very VERY NICE! For my own understanding will you confirm if this is correct or not: `class << self` in a sense creates an additional definition for the class that is it's self, return the object that is the definition object of it's self and through `send(:attr_reader, :hello)` creates the desired `attr_reader`?

Comment: @KurtRudolph, yeah that's pretty much right. Just make sure you understand that every object instance has it's very own class. You can put method there that *only* affect that instance, not other instances of the class. And "class << self" is how you open the eigenclass (and as you said, it returns a reference to itself, then uses send to create the desired attribute reader).

Comment: @KurtRudolph, I undid your edit to my answer. Your edit was *different*, not just simpler. Henrik's gist that you linked to makes it so "hello" always returns the *initial* value of arg, so it works completely different than an attribute reader. The way I have it, it works *identically* to an attribute reader, so you can set `@hello = ...` and get the expected `obj.hello` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your response, you have repeated answered my questions and each time you answers are well worded and thorough.  Not only that, you take the time to help me understand the why of the questions going beyond simply telling me how to fix the current issue.  Cheers BenLee

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but you can use [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) to get an initializer and accessor methods:

```
class SomeClass < Struct.new(:hello)
end

x = SomeClass.new("yo")
puts x.hello  # "yo"
x.hello = "what up"
puts x.hello  # "what up"
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.  I partially want it for dynamic purposes and I partially want it just because I'm trying not repeat my self by just stating in one command that the along with the instance variable there should be according methods allowing access to it, i.e `p = SomeClass.new 'world'; puts p.hello' should output the string `world` without having to state separately `attr_reader :hello` and `@hello = arg`

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'ostruct'

p = OpenStruct.new
p.hello = 'world'
p.could_be_anything = 'nothing'
puts p.hello #=> 'world'
puts p.could_be_anything #=> 'nothing'
```